# When using a list comprehension, is there a way to mention it in itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi guys I'm using a list comprehension for a very simple task, is there a way to mention its own list in itself, what I mean by this, is... if for example I have the following code:

```
def intersection(list_1, list_2):
    return [item for item in list_1 if item in list_2]
```

The code is basically returning a list with all the items that both `list_1` and `list_2` have, it works, but I want it to also check if the item is not already stored in itself, so then that way there is no duplicates, I want to keep the order so that is why `set()` is not an option, something to note is that I want to know if there is a way of doing something like this:

```
 [item for item in list_1 if item in list_2 and not in 'itself']
```

I would love to learn other ways of achieving the same, but my main question is if that is possible or not. I also want to mention I am aware that is achievable using a for loop.

Comment: It seems that you want to avoid duplicates in your resulting list. Have you considered using set comprehension?

Comment: You need either `set` or a for-loop to reference an external set to check

Comment: I'd say using a set is still your best option. You can then reorder using first list's index: `sorted(set(lst1).intersection(lst2), key=lst1.index)`

Comment: @ayhan thank you for that! From your answer I imagine it is not possible doing what my question asked, and thank you for another solution, I also had a question about the key you were using, personally I would have done key = lambda x: lst1.index(x) since I didn't know there was a shorter and clearner way, but I was wondering why in your key you don't need to add the brackets after .index like so: `key = lst1.index()` why are you able to do just `key = lst1.index` aren't the brackets necessary?

Comment: Because argument `key` of `sorted` takes a function to be called. Put differently, `lst1.index` is callable, while `lst1.index()` is called.

Comment: @keepAlive oh so that is why It won't let me put `lst1.index()` as my key (it raises an erro r TypeError) because it is being called where as when you pass in `lst1.index` as the key, behind the scenes `sorted()` is doing the following for each item `lst1.index(item)` and that is how it knows how to sort it from smallest index to biggest?

Comment: Exactly ! You can use `key` argument to use your own rule. An illustrative (but meaningless) example:  `key= lambda el: lst1.index(el)%3`. Incidentally, `lst1.index` takes an element to be found within `lst1`, and if found, returns its index.

Comment: @keepAlive Thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
final_list = [list_1[i] for i in range(len(list_1)) if list_1[i] in list_2 and list_1[i] not in list_1[:i]]
```

or this,

```
[item for i, item in enumerate(list_1) if item in list_2 and item not in list_1[:i]]
```

whichever is more comfortable to you

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting question. I'm not sure how to reference the list comprehension as it's being built, or if its memory can be accessed while the list is being constructed.

Here's some ways that I've tried:

```
def intersection(l1: list[int], l2: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    # Return list intersection without dups using sets and list comp
    l1, l2 = set(l1), set(l2)
    return [i for i in l1 if i in l2]

def intersection2(l1: list[int], l2: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    # Return list intersection without dups using sets and list comp
    return list(set([i for i in l1 if i in l2 and i]))

def intersection3(l1: list[int], l2: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    # Return list intersection optimal
    return intersection(l1, l2)

listOne = [1,2,3,4,5]
listTwo = [4,5,6,7,8]

print(intersection(listOne,listTwo), '\n')
print(intersection2(listOne,listTwo), '\n')
print(intersection3(listOne,listTwo))
```

Comment: what do the `l1: list, l2: list` when you are declaring your parameters for every function, I'm asking because I have never seen that used

Comment: PEP484 adds type hints: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/
 
So you can optionally add type hints for ease of use for another developer using your methods.